# Prevent powershell properties from resetting after system update

Tags: windows-10, powershell, default-settings

Every time Windows updates, the "Windows Powershell" Properties get reset to the original defaults. For the Colors tab that looks like this

[image]

I don't like these defaults and every time Windows updates I have to go back and change them again to the settings I want. I'm looking for a way to avoid needing to manually reset them every time (e.g. some way to set them via script, or some way to force the changes to persist across updates).

I have tried setting the desired properties in the Defaults:

[image]

The changes there appear to persist between updates but I can't figure out how to make the properties follow these defaults instead of the 'original' values.

The specific properties I want to change are the color values and the opacity in the colors tab and the terminal colors and cursor shape in the terminal tab.

I came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1309726/backup-modified-powershell-console-colors-properties-windows-10), but the answers there didn't lead me to any solution for updating the color values themselves - only which color is used for background and foreground

Is there any way to make these changes with a script or reset the properties to the values in the Defaults tab instead of the 'original' defaults?

Comment: Look at this post and under the host private data area to see if this helps you. I am not certain. https://beebom.com/how-change-powershell-color-scheme-windows-10/  I cannot find another way to make properties stick.

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestion - that seems to be similar to the question I linked in that it shows how to change which color is being used for what (i.e. setting the `errorforeground` color to `"Green"`) but what I want to do is change the RGB values for the colors (i.e. `"Green"` to be `(0, 225, 50)` instead of `(0, 255, 0)` for example)... I don't see anywhere in that post which demonstrates how to do that

Comment: Once you make your settings, save those setting off to a file, and use that to reset to what you had previously. You can set that in your PowerShell profile so, that it loads each time.

Comment: @postanote That sounds like exactly what I want to do. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a script to change the desired parameters. This is the script:

```
Push-Location
Set-Location HKCU:\Console
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable00 -type DWORD -value 0x00000000
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable01 -type DWORD -value 0x007a4d38
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable02 -type DWORD -value 0x00276112
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable03 -type DWORD -value 0x00abab00
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable04 -type DWORD -value 0x00333391
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable05 -type DWORD -value 0x00911f91
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable06 -type DWORD -value 0x0000ebeb
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable07 -type DWORD -value 0x00afafaf
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable08 -type DWORD -value 0x00646464
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable09 -type DWORD -value 0x00fc6e47
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable10 -type DWORD -value 0x0047fc47
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable11 -type DWORD -value 0x00ffff33
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable12 -type DWORD -value 0x003d33ff
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable13 -type DWORD -value 0x00ff33ff
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable14 -type DWORD -value 0x008fffff
Set-ItemProperty . ColorTable15 -type DWORD -value 0x00ffffff
Set-ItemProperty . WindowAlpha  -type DWORD -value 0x000000d9
Pop-Location

$path = "C:\Users\words\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\"+
        "Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk"
rm $path
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\words\AppData\Roaming\"+
    "Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk")
$shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
```

The first chunk sets the RGB values of the terminal colors and the opacity of the window, the second chunk updates the Start Menu shortcut so that the changes take effect even when launching from the start menu. I have saved the script as `~\colors.ps1` and simply run

```
PS C:\ ~\colors.ps1
```

and then restart PowerShell anytime an update reverts my settings to the original defaults.