# Set Console Colors when Creating Shortcut with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, colors, shortcuts, console

I can use code like this to create a shortcut file in PowerShell:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$PSScriptRoot/myshortcut.lnk")
$Shortcut.Arguments = "./myscript.py"
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $myexepath
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "$PSScriptRoot"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

I would like to adjust this Powershell code to change the console colors of the created output .lnk file. From this answer here, https://superuser.com/a/1309729, I know that the console colors are stored directly in the .lnk file (I also observed this myself doing a binary comparison on the .lnk file before and after changing the color through the GUI).

**How can I specify the console colors when using the above method to create a shortcut file?** Hopefully I don't have to change the created .lnk file byte by byte in order to achieve this. I also definitely don't want to change the registry to do this; I want the colors to be specific to the created .lnk file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a shortcut to a console app,the `Properties` dialog for the resulting shortcut has four tabs specific to the console appearance:
[image]

Unfortunately, those settings are not exposed by the `wscript.shell` com object, so if you want to modify the console colors specified by the `.lnk` file, you have to do some byte-level editing of the file. If you're able to copy from an existing shortcut with your desired colors, it should be relatively easy --- *once you know what bytes you want to copy.*

Looking at the spec-sheet [[MS-SHLLINK]: Shell Link (.LNK) Binary File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943) reveals:

> **2.5.1 ConsoleDataBlock**
>
> The ConsoleDataBlock structure specifies the display settings to use when a link target specifies an application that is run in a console window.

... and the block has a constant size and always begins with a specific byte sequence:

> **BlockSize (4 bytes)**: A 32-bit, unsigned integer that specifies the size of the ConsoleDataBlock structure. This value MUST be 0x000000CC.
>
> **BlockSignature (4 bytes)**: A 32-bit, unsigned integer that specifies the signature of the ConsoleDataBlock extra data section. This value MUST be 0xA0000002.

As a sequence of raw bytes, that would be:

```
CC 00 00 00 02 00 00 A0
```

### Edit #2 --- Code Overhaul

My initial code was based on byte operations, and there are numerous examples out there. But there is a way to search and manipulate byte arrays as strings and leverage the power of regualr expressions explained in [Use PowerShell and Regular Expressions to Search Binary Data](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-and-regular-expressions-to-search-binary-data/):

> Unfortunately, none of the encoding schemes that are allowed in Get-Content provide a one-to-one mapping of characters back to its respective byte value. There is a magic encoding scheme that does, however: ISO-8859-1 (Codepage: 28591).

To create the magically encodeed string, instances of the .net classes [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-7.0#methods) and [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-7.0) must be created. The resulting string can be manipulated with regular expressions.

```
$BlockSource  = 'C:\Path\to\LinkWithCustomizedConsoleSettings.lnk'
$Lnk2Edit     = 'C:\Path\to\LinkToBeCustomized.lnk'

### -------------------------- Code based on -------------------------- ###
### ----------------- Use PowerShell and Regular Expressions to Search Binary Data ----------------- ###
###   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-and-regular-expressions-to-search-binary-data/   ###

$DataSize    = 0xCC - 8 
$BlockHeader = '\xCC\x00{3}\x02\x00{2}\xA0'

Function Get-BytesAsText ( [String] $Path )
{ Process {
    $Stream = [IO.FileStream]::new($Path, 'Open', 'Read' )
    $Reader = [IO.StreamReader]::new( $Stream , ([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591)))
    $Reader.ReadToEnd()
    $Reader.Close()
    $Stream.Close()
}}

Function Get-BlockOffset ( [String] $ByteString )
    { Process { [Regex]::Match( $ByteString , $BlockHeader ).Index }}

Function Get-ConsoleBlock ( [String] $ByteString )
    { Process { [Regex]::Match( $ByteString , "$BlockHeader.{$DataSize}" ).Value }}

###   Main   ###

$ByteText           = Get-BytesAsText $BlockSource    
$CustomConsoleBlock = Get-ConsoleBlock $ByteText

$ByteText           = Get-BytesAsText $Lnk2Edit
$Offset             = Get-BlockOffset $ByteText

If ( $Offset )   ### Replace existing console block
{
    $Pattern        = "$BlockHeader.{$DataSize}"
    $NewBytes       = [Regex]::Replace( $ByteText , $Pattern , $CustomConsoleBlock )
}
Else             ### Insert before terminal block
{
    Write-Verbose 'No existing Console Block'
    $Pattern        = '\x00{4}$'
    $NewBytes       = [Regex]::Replace( $ByteText , $Pattern , ($CustomConsoleBlock + "$([string][char]0x00 * 4)") )
}
[Byte[]][Char[]]$NewBytes | Set-Content $Lnk2Edit -Encoding Byte -Force
```

---

### End of edit #2

---

---

### THis is the original post and frist edit -- retained only for historical purposed! :D

So, to copy the console data block from an existing shortcut to a byte array:

```
$BlockSize       = [Byte]0xCC
$HeaderAsUint64  = [system.BitConverter]::ToUInt64([Byte[]](0xCC,0,0,0,2,0,0,0xA0),0)

$SourcePath      = 'C:\CustomizedShortut.lnk'

$SourceBytes     = [Byte[]](Get-Content $SourcePath -Encoding Byte)

$BlockOffset     = $SourceBytes.IndexOf($BlockSize)

If ( [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt64($SourceBytes,$BlockOffset) -eq $HeaderAsUint64 )
{
    $ConsoleBytes = [Byte[]]($SourceBytes[$BlockOffset..($BlockOffset + $BlockSize - 1)])
    # Create an assignment string to paste into shortcut creattion code
    '$ConsoleBytes = [Byte[]]@({0})' -f ($ConsoleBytes -join ',') | Set-Clipboard
}
Else
{
    # Modify code to loop on byte search + sequence verification
    # until header is found. In my limited testing, the 0xCC byte
    # only occured once, so this wasn't necessary.
}
```

Then in your shortcut creation code, paste the expression the previous code copied to the clipboard and use it to edit your newly created shortcut:

### EDIT:Code modified to add block to shortcuts that don't originally have one.

```
# <ctrl>+V
$ConsoleBytes    = [Byte[]]@(204,0,0,0,2,0,0,160,101,0,202,0,120,0,184,11,120,0,47,0,96,0,108,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,28,0,54,0,0,0,144,1,0,0,67,0,111,0,110,0,115,0,111,0,108,0,97,0,115,0,0,0,101,0,49,0,53,0,0,0,0,0,249,127,0,0,140,176,8,154,213,73,0,0,0,0,55,1,250,127,0,0,169,232,245,31,0,0,0,0,145,71,151,231,249,127,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,0,0,128,0,0,0,128,128,0,128,0,0,0,1,36,86,0,238,237,240,0,192,192,192,0,128,128,128,0,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,255,0,0,0,255,0,255,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,0)
$BlockSize       = [Byte]0xCC

$MyShortCutPath  = "$PSScriptRoot\myshortcut.lnk"

$MyShortCutBytes = Get-Content $MyShortCutPath -Encoding Byte

$BlockOffset     = $MyShortCutBytes.IndexOf($BlockSize)

### Added code for shortcuts created without a Console Data Block
### As Extra Data Blocks are identified by signature, the order of
### the blocks doesn't matter within the Extra Data section. Thus,
### The custom Console Data Block can be appended just prior to the
### 4-byte Terminal Block.

If ($BlockOffset -eq -1)
{
    $BlockOffset = $MyShortCutBytes.Length - 4
    $BlockSize   = 0
}

[Byte[]]($MyShortCutBytes[0..($BlockOffset - 1)]) +
    $ConsoleBytes +
    [Byte[]]($MyShortCutBytes[($BlockOffset + $BlockSize)..($MyShortCutBytes.Length - 1)]) |
        Set-Content $MyShortCutPath -Encoding Byte -Force
```

- Note that this code is copying the entire console block with all the settings specified in the linked documentation. If you wanted to be more "surgically precise", you could extract/modify only the `FillAttributes`, `PopupFillAttributes` and `ColorTable` sections of the console block. As their offsets are constant from the beginning of the cosole data block, that would be a relatively trivial modification to the code.

Comment: Very helpful. One thing I noticed is that not every shortcut file seems to have a `sConsoleDataBlock` section. In other words, I don't see the byte sequence of `CC 00 00 00 02 00 00 A0` in every .lnk file I've examined (I've seen it in some but not others). Is this section only created once I have modified the .lnk file properties through the GUI? Or is there someway to force this struct to be present when creating the .lnk file from the `wscript.shell` com object?

Comment: First of all, you'll only see it in shortcuts that run an executable in a console window, not a program like **MS Word** or **Libre Office**. But I also noticed that the default shortcut to **Command Prompt** in my `shell:Programs\System Tools`  folder doesn't have a `ConsoleDataBlock` section, so perhaps it's omitted if all console settings remain at their default.

Comment: @jippyjoe4: Further testing revealed that shortcuts that reference `cmd.exe` as the shortcut target executable don't have a Console Data Block because none of the default console settings are modified. In that case, your custom Console Data Block can be appended to the new shortcut. See edit to answer for details.

Comment: I appreciate your update, however, I'm noticing that my shortcut files definitely have a `CC` byte earlier than extra data block, so your scripts are not working. I will have to modify it to copy the bytes to the correct location.

Comment: I was curous if that could occur, but had limited samples. Could you share a shortcut file where that occurs? I'd like to determine what section it's in.

Comment: Sure. This is the .lnk file without the console block section. It appears in the `ShellLinkHeader` section under the `uint32 FileSize` area. https://i.imgur.com/ESTmfKr.png. Here is a pastebin of the hex bytes: https://pastebin.com/ShhKvBNJ.

Comment: Edit #2 should take care of the issues you encountered and prove quite robust if you add the usual error checking. The techiniques are a great addtion to anyone's toolbox!

Comment: Interesting. This appeared to copy over the bytes, but when running the shortcut the console color still did not change. It seems like there are some other structural differences in the file that are not accounted for when editing the shortcut through the GUI. https://i.imgur.com/SuoQkKr.png The top file is the GUI modified one, while the bottom one was produced using Wscript and your new method copying the bytes from the GUI modified one.

Comment: In my initial testing, the order of the ExtraData blocks didin't matter, as they're identified by signature. Afrer seeing your comment, I found that both code & GUI modified shortcuts worked as expected when launched from **Explorer** (my initaial testing), but *both* failed to display the custom colors *when launched from an open **cmd.exe** console with the default colors in effect. Are you sure that's not what you're seeing.